# How to JSON stringify a javascript New Date

Tags: javascript, json, stringify, dataformat

I'm getting data from the form's json when the user fills out the calendar

```
const data= JSON.stringify(orderForm.informationDate));
```

Currently, I get data from JSON to print PDF in any way:

```
{"year":2023,"month":12,"day":22}
```

How to change data to DD.MM.YYYY format?

Comment: TIP - you will probably be better off in the long term sticking to the ISO-8601 standard when you want to keep the date as machine readable as possible i.e. '2023-12-22'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to not store the date in dd.mm.yyyy format but if you insist

```js
const orderForm = { informationDate: {"year": 2023, "month": 12, "day": 22} };

const ddmmyyyy = Object.values(orderForm.informationDate)
  .reverse()
  .map(val => String(val).padStart(2, '0'))
  .join('.');

console.log(ddmmyyyy); // Outputs: 22.12.2023


// With a replacer function


const replacer = (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'informationDate')
    return Object.values(value)
      .reverse()
      .map(val => String(val).padStart(2, '0'))
      .join('.');
  return value;
}

const jsonString = JSON.stringify({ orderForm }, replacer, 2);
console.log(jsonString);
```

Comment: I found a solution const test = JSON.stringify(orderForm.informaitonDate).replace(/{"year":(\d+),"month":(\d+),"day":(\d+)}/, '$3.$2.$1');

Comment: Sure. That would work too.

Comment: @mplungjan are you serious? You're recommending against serializing to a specific format, but you're ok with running a regex find & replace?

Comment: I am not really, but in this simple case it would work

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on a few misunderstandings:

1. Dates cannot be serialized to/from json - there is no date/time data type.
2. When you provide a date to the json serializer, you are providing an object, hence the serializer generates an object representation, like you saw:

   ```js
   const myFakeDate = { year: 2023, month: 12, day: 22 };
   console.log(JSON.stringify(myFakeDate)); // => {"year":2023,"month":12,"day":22}
   ```
3. The format that you mention in your question is clearly a string, since dates are typically stored internally as a number, not a string
4. In your case, you have two options:

   1. convert the date/time object to a string before calling `JSON.stringify`:

      ```js
      const data= {
         name: "John Doe",
         birthDate: {year: 1982, month: 3, day: 4}
      };

      data.birthDate = data.birthDate.day + '.' + data.birthDate.month + '.' + data.birthDate.year;

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      ```
   2. Or use the "replacer" functionality:

      ```js
      const data= {
         name: "John Doe",
         birthDate: {year: 1982, month: 3, day: 4}
      };

      const replacer = function(item) {
         if (item.year && item.month && item.day) {
           return item.day + '.' + item.month + '.' + item.year;
         }

         return item;
      };

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data, replacer));
      ```
5. Keep in mind that you would/might need to reverse the process on the other side (e.g. to convert the string back to a date)
6. If you are using Datetime objects (and not a plain object), you can check the object class instead of the existence of day/month/year properties. This depends on your exact code.

Comment: I found a solution const test = JSON.stringify(orderForm.informaitonDate).replace(/{"year":(\d+),"month":(\d+),"day":(\d+)}/, '$3.$2.$1');

Comment: @I'mstilllearning that's a terrible solution. If your date object changes structure - even just the order of the properties, it will not work anymore. By the way, it also depends on the serializer...`JSON.stringify` might add spaces or newlines, which again will break that code.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the attributes of this object (data.year, data.month, data.day) and concatenate into a string

`${data.day}.${data.month}.${data.year}`

Comment: Fairly naïve approach that would result in "2023.1.1" instead of "2023.01.01"

Answer (score 0):

1. **Use the power of destructuring.**
2. The format function role is to make sure days and months like `2`
   becomes `02`.

```js
const date = {year: 2023, month: 12, day: 22};
const { year, month, day } = date;
const format = (str) => String(str).padStart('0', 2);
const formattedDate = `${format(day)}.${format(month)}.${year}`;
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(formattedDate);
console.log(formattedDate);
console.log(jsonData);
```